# Multisite setup help - plain domain/subsite always redirects to domain with subdir multisite

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess, directory, wp-redirect

I set up a path-based wp multisite using subdirs for each site.  It all works well except if the subsite is accessed without www.  For example -

`//mainsite/subsite` always redirects to `//mainsite"`

`//www.mainsite/subsite"` always redirects to `//www.mainsite/subsite"`

I'd like to have requests made without the www to also redirect to the subsite.

i.e `//mainsite/subsite"` redirect to `//www.mainsite/subsite"`

I've tried htaccess rules - but nothing seems to work

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subsite/$1  [NC]
RewriteRule ^www.mainsite.com/subsite/$1 [L,R=301]
```

All wildcards are setup in DNS to direct to www and apache config has plain domain as the servername with alias of www.

Has anyone run across this before?

Apologies for the code - I can't post more than two http links apparently so assume anything with a `//` has an `http:` in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

You're close.

I added a few more places to capture more scenarios and used the HTTP_HOST variable in the rule. The `$1` is not needed in the condition as that would match what's captured in the above condition.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subsite/? [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I recommend [Made With Love's .htaccess check](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) to verify your testing.